# How to use AWS SSO to authenticate against Application Load Balancer (ALB)?

Tags: amazon-web-services

How can I use AWS SSO to allow users to authenticate against an Application Load Balancer (ALB)? Here's a link to the [ALB authentication announcement](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/built-in-authentication-in-alb/).

Can AWS SSO integrate directly into ALB authentication, or is it necessary to do something like use an AWS Cognito Identity Pool to manage access to the ALB, and federate the pool to AWS SSO?

Answer (score 0):

AWS SSO uses SAML 2.0 to support application authentication, while ALB supports OIDC and Cognito. To use AWS SSO with an ALB, you need to set up an AWS Cognito User Pool and configure the ALB to use that for authentication, and then set up AWS SSO as a SAML Identity Provider for that User Pool.